# Bootloader on sda broken when installing from sdb to sdc?

Tags: grub2, live-usb

Last week I tried to install Xen and ruined my bootloader, so I reinstalled fresh 19.04 on my 480GB SSD (sda) using LUKS encryption.

Today I booted into a 19.04 Live-USB (sdb) and installed Ubuntu onto a second 120GB USB (sdc) for a side project.  During installation, I formatted the 120GB to ext4 and installed both the OS and the boot loader to the 120GB (sdc) drive.

Now, when I turn on my laptop without either pen drive plugged in, I expect to get back into the Ubuntu I installed last week - but I just get a GRUB 2 menu offering tabcomplete instructions.

What happened to my boot loader?!  Can anyone help me get back in?

Edit, in response to C.S. Cameron:
Now that I look more closely at my boot options, there is only one drive listed - its label is that of the 480GB I wish to access.  Except, it boots to the pen drive install.  So, I would imagine this indicates (major novice here) the UUIDs are mixed up.  Would you mind confirming that?
Since I can't seem to mount the 480GB LUKS SSD (password prompt appears in nautilus, but the drive vanishes afterward) I cannot check /etc/fstab to confirm or edit...

And in response to Oldfred:
Last week I tried fixing the same problem with boot-repair and it went badly; I was only able to get to an initramfs prompt afterward.  Reading online showed a more experienced user attributed this to our mutual LUKS encryption.  I'll try again if nothing else works.

Heartfelt thanks to both of you for your answers, at least I know what to read now.

Comment: Last install normally is first in UEFI or BIOS boot order. And only a small part of grub in in MBR (BIOS) or ESP (UEFI) and rest is inside / (root). So your flash drive install may have grub on internal drive, but rest of grub on flash drive. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &

Comment: With encrypted LVM, you have to mount LVM & decrypt install for Boot-Repair to work. If not then you have the issues you found where grub is not correctly installed. New installs now also keep /boot inside / (root) inside LVM. Boot-Repair may expect a separate /boot outside LVM to work. Or maybe new LVM  versions do not work with Boot-Repair. Then you have to chroot and do it the old fashion way to manually reinstall grub.